# Binary logs in Magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, database, deploy

We are a team working with Magento 1.7. In order to manage deployment between different developer working with the same database of Magento. We suggest to use **binary logs**.

Each developer will possess his own Magento environment in localhost. To deploy into server, we are using Git for deploying files, and for the database, each developer has Mysql Workbench to generate a binary log of his database, each binary log will be deploying into server and Git will synchronise one database into server.

We prefer avoiding working in the same database. What do you think about this solution? Any suggestions please.

Comment: what do you mean by Binary logs?

Comment: @FlorinelChis binary logs are like an event log that allow point-in-time recovery. They're instrumental in replication set ups. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html

Comment: @philwinkle great, now hoes does that make sense looking at what he is trying to do... I thought he meant something else by binary logs, something specific to his stuff...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A novel but terrible idea :-). Will blow up miserably due to foreign key collisions.

Better to use proper setup scripts for non-conflicting changes. For settings and entity fixtures use a common setup module or two and enforce consistency via git workflow.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Please could you give me more details.

Comment: Here's a tutorial on setup scripts and the config & resources which declare & run them: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-6-magento-setup-resources

Comment: Thank you very much Benmarks. Do you think that this issue is the best way to managinh deployement in Magento ? Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with @benmarks, and this answer is supplemental to his correct answer.

If you're looking to **batch** updates, you can try one of the upgrade batch extensions that have cropped up from ECG or from Fabrizio Branca / AOE. This, like your MySQL binary log idea, is a way of aggregating updates into discrete batches that can be run at-will.

I've never tried these plugins, though in the past (EE1.10 -> EE1.11) I desperately wish that I had them.

Fabrizio Branca's Upgrade Replay:

https://github.com/fbrnc/Magento-Upgrade-Replay

Magento's ECG derivative of that same codebase:

https://github.com/magento-ecg/Magento-Upgrade-Replay

Answer (score 0):

Ben is 100% correct here (as usual).

When developing, use deployment scripts.  This way, schema changes are propagated out to your developers (and to your environments) in a relatively seamless mannor.

An additional word of advice... if you ever find yourself, as a developer, clicking "create attribute" ... stop, and do it via an attribute installer script.  Migration of attributes in Magento is non-existent outside of adding it to your install scripts.

Down the line, when you've added 20 custom attributes you're going to be wishing you had done the work up front.

Create them via admin for testing them all you want but delete them and recreate them via install script for your team and sanity.

Comment: Thank you very much guys for your advises. But as a novice developer, could you please give some resources in creating deployment scripts. Thank you very much.

Comment: For module setup scripts (say you create a module that has custom database tables), [Ben's link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-6-magento-setup-resources) is a great resource.

Comment: For attribute setup scripts (the same thing as above really, you're just telling the script to setup attributes instead), [this is a really good place to start](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/installing_custom_attributes_with_your_module).

Comment: My second link for attribute setup didn't come through the parser correctly.  [This one](http://bit.ly/cFPPgd) should work better.